# Failure to get evaluation copies of SQL Server 2019 and SQL Server Reporting Services linked in SQL Server Management Studio 18.5

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have downloaded, installed, & tried to configure evaluation copies of 2019 SQL Server & 2017 SSRS.

When I used Report Server Configuration Manager, I put my new instance of the SQL database engine (MSSQLSERVER05) into the database name.
This connected properly.

Through multiple tries, I have created multiple report servers & temp report servers.
However, when I try to access SSRS from the Object Explorer of SSMS 18.5, 2 old DB names & "SSRS" are the only instances I see.

I have tried using SSRS, but the error says the reporting service instance cannot be found.
If I type in the name of the new database engine (MSSQLSERVER05), I get the same error.
I have had earlier trials of SQL, but tried to uninstall all of them.
I notice that the file rsreportserver.config has "SSRS" in it as well as a coded database name.

This likely needs to change somehow. I would appreciate any help!
Thanks!
Ginger

Comment: *"configure evaluation copies of 2019 SQL Server & 2017 SSRS"* Why, out of interest, are you using 2019 as your database engine and 2017 as your SSRS instance? Why 2 separate instances, and why different versions?

Comment: I downloaded these two separately.  I did not see an evaluation copy of 2019 SSRS.  I have used SQL Server as a data analyst for some time but have never had to install it.  SSRS is fairly new to me.  Ginger

Answer (score 0):

First, use Developer Edition instead of Evaluation Edition for non-production scenarios, as it's not timebombed.

> when I try to access SSRS from the Object Explorer of SSMS 18.5,

There's not really much use in using SSMS to connect to the Report Server.  Just open the Report Manager Portal in your browser.

[image]

> old DB names & "SSRS" are the only instances I see

Not sure, but SSRS 2017 is not installed as part of a SQL Server instance, and you can't have multiple instances installed on a computer.  This change was part of the transition of SSRS be a scaled-down edition of [Power BI Report Server](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/report-server/).

Comment: Thanks, David! That is helpful.  How do you open up the Report Manager Portal in a browser?  I am doing this installation in order to take an SSRS course and then create some work samples to send to interested employers.  Will I be able to do that with the developer edition?  If I can, should I uninstall everything I can find SQL related & install again?  What about that rsreportserver.config file?  Thanks, Ginger

Comment: The Report Manager URL is configured in the Report Server Configuration Manager.  See picture in updated answer.  You might want to enable Hyper-V and install an Eval version of Windows Server 2019 in a VM to get a clean server environment.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v and https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2019

Comment: I have installed SQL Server 2019 w/SSRS developer edition.  I am not able to connect to SSRS using the http address due to security software currently.  I hope to hear back from them later today about a possible resolution with this security software.  I am going to ask a new more specific question about connecting from SSMS Object Explorer right now.  I appreciate all your help, David..